# Carbon - Getting only part of a TimeStamp

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a timestamp in my database:
`2017-10-01 04:32:37`

Now, I need to grab only the date, so like "01/10"

I'm trying to do this with Laravel's Carbon library, can anyone tell me how? I can't find anything to do with this in the documentation, it seems unheard of?

I want to do this with Carbon

Answer (score 1):

Its been a long time since I used PHP and Laravel so I may be wrong.
But you can use `$carbon->format("format string")` to make any string you want out of your carbon instances

My guess you can do something like:

```
Carbon::now()->format("d/m");
```

Answer (score 1):

field `created_at` and `updated_at` returned as Carbon object, you can directly format that attributes like this

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
// created at value
// 2017-12-20 06:30:25
$user->created_at->format('d/m');
// will return
// 20/12
```

or if you have custom date attributes you can use `Carbon::parse()` methods like this

```
$approvedAt = '2017-10-02 05:30:00';
$initDate = Carbon::parse($approvedAt);
$approvedAtFormated = $initDate->format('d/m');
// will return
// 02/10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use format

```
$re=  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2017-10-01 04:32:37')->format('d/m');
 dd($re);
```

output

```
   "01/10"
```

Also you can use

```
 $updated_at=Carbon::parse( '2017-10-01 04:32:37')->format('d/m');;
      dd($updated_at);
```

output

```
"01/10"
```

If you are converting `updated_at` and **created_at** then you directly format datetime using carbon

for example

```
$blogTag=Tag::retrieveTagById(1);
dd($blogTag->created_at->format('d/m'));
```

Output will be

```
"01/10"
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the ["String Formatting" section](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) of the Carbon docs, we can use the `format()` method to produce any format that PHP understands:

```
Carbon::parse('2017-10-01 04:32:37')->format('d/m');
// "01/10"
```

Carbon supports the same [format notations](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) as PHP's `strtotime()` function and `DateTime` class.

Laravel automatically converts any Eloquent model attributes declared in a model's `$dates` or `$casts` arrays to Carbon instances. This lets us use Carbon-specific functionality without the need to manually parse the date into Carbon:

```
$user->created_at->format('d/m');
$user->last_login->format('d/m');
```